# How to use "mapping.txt" file for debug and error-exception handler for Release version in Android

Tags: android, error-handling, exception, proguard

I want to upload errors to the user in the app to the database server, but in the **Release version**, because it's used with **Proguard**, it does not correctly represent the classes that have encountered the error, as in the example Has been laid.

***Sample error message***

```
Attempt to write to field 'java.lang.String com.employe.school.Application.Message.c.c' on 
a null object reference
```

***Instead of "c.c", your actual class name will be displayed.***

In general, I want to handle the App errors myself and do not use Firebase or other crash reporters.

***Is there a way to solve this problem?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android studio create mapping(build/outputs/mapping/release/mapping.txt) file under release folder for Release builds. You can use them to find out where the error is occured. Re-mapping is already implemented on Google Play Console and crashlytics. You just put mapping file with corresponding APK to play console and errors are shown correctly.

Comment: I want to handle the App errors myself and do not use Firebase or other crash reporters.

Comment: Then you need to parse the error stacktrace and replace items with the ones in the mapping

Answer (score 3):

```
%SDK_DIR%\tools\proguard\bin\retrace mapping.txt errors.txt > fixed.txt
```

Do the work.